# Java streams - Get max two objects depending on condition

Tags: java, java-stream, max

Relatively new to java streams and I have encountered an issue which I could not find a solution for.

I have A list of 10 objects and filtered them to return 4 objects.

```
List<MyObject> objects.stream()
                      .filter(x -> x.getFlag == 1)
                      .filter(x -> x.amount != null)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**this returns 4 objects:**

```
OBJECT 1: {stageNumber = 2, stageToCalc = 1}
OBJECT 2: {stageNumber = 5, stageToCalc = 1}
OBJECT 3: {stageNumber = 9, stageToCalc = 7}
OBJECT 4: {stageNumber = 10, stageToCalc = 7}
```

So basically what I am trying to do is take stages that have the same value of stageToCalc
and find the maximium stageNumber.

E.G: object 3 and object 4 have the same stageToCalc = 7, maximum value according to stage number should return Object 4: {stageNumber = 10, stageToCalc = 7} which is the ***higher*** value.

however,
my issue comes when I need to get 2 (or more since it might be dynamic).
*in this case :*

it should return **object 2** and **Object 4.**

I have tried using:

```
objects.stream()
       .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, toList())
       .lastEntry()
       .getValue()
       .forEach(System.out::println)
```

This will just result in a `classCastException`, and if I Use `.max()` it would not compile.
I could easy accomplish this in an expensive way with some for loops etc.

however I wonder if there is a way in using just 1 stream iteration.

Hope I am clear on this question.
Still new and learning.

THANKS.

Comment: The question would be much clear if you provide it with the [*Minimal reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I.e. expose the code of `MyObject` (field that are relevant to the problem), and give a code sample with an initialized list of these objects - so that everyone can execute your code.

Comment: You question is stated as *Get max **two** objects*, then you are saying *A list of `10` objects and filtered them to return `4` objects*. So `2` or `4` ? And in the code snippets, you're not limiting the number of results anyhow. You've also mentioned `max()` operation, it produces an optional object containing a single value (or empty). So how many objects are required?

Comment: Lets say I have 4 objects 2 objects have the same 'stageToCalc' and the other two have also the same 'StageToCalc' now what seperates them is who has the higher 'StageNumber'. thats what I mean. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: I will edit a more clear description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy()` with a downstream `Collectors.maxBy()` to get the appropriate objects (With `Collectors.collectAndThen()` to pull them out of the `Optional` values returned by `maxBy()`):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {
    private record MyObject(int stageNumber, int stageToCalc) {}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyObject> objects = List.of(new MyObject(2, 1), new MyObject(5, 1), new MyObject(9, 7), new MyObject(10, 7));;

        List<MyObject>  maximums =
            new ArrayList<>(objects.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::stageToCalc,
                                                           Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::stageNumber)),
                                                                                        Optional::orElseThrow)))
                            .values());
    System.out.println(maximums);
    }
}
```

will print out

```
[MyObject[stageNumber=5, stageToCalc=1], MyObject[stageNumber=10, stageToCalc=7]]
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason I get a NullPointerException. maybe since my real Object is a little different,. ELEMENT CANNOT BE MAPPED TO A NULL KEY

Comment: You of course have to update the getter methods to whatever your MyObject class calls them. If the values are not ints but are some object type that can be null... stuff like that is really important to mention in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Collectors.toMap():

```
public record MyObject(int stageNumber, int stageToCalc) {}


List<MyObject> objects = List.of(
        new MyObject(1, 1),
        new MyObject(5, 1),
        new MyObject(3, 1),
        new MyObject(1, 2),
        new MyObject(5, 3),
        new MyObject(1, 3)
);

Map<Integer, MyObject> result = objects.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                MyObject::stageToCalc,
                Function.identity(),
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::stageNumber))
        ));


System.out.println(result.values());
```

Output:

```
[MyObject[stageNumber=5, stageToCalc=1], MyObject[stageNumber=1, stageToCalc=2], MyObject[stageNumber=5, stageToCalc=3]]
```